# VBScript remove newline

Tags: vbscript

I have an HTML page with one or more newlines after `</html>`. My VBScript file is able to find the replace the newlines with emptiness. But, it looks like OpenTextFile is putting a newline at the end again. Help!

```
'Pulled this from the InterWebs
Const ForReading = 1 Const ForWriting = 2
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("a.html", ForReading)
strText = objFile.ReadAll
'Wscript.Echo strText
objFile.Close

strNewText = Replace(strText, "</html>" & vbCrlf, "</html>")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("a.txt", ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText
objFile.Close
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `objFile.WriteLine strNewText` use `objFile.Write strNewText`. This will write the file without a newline at the end.

BTW, another way of removing the newline(s) from after your `</html>` tag would be `strNewText = Trim(strText)` instead of using `Replace()`

Answer (score 3):

This may help:

The TextStream object has the following important methods for writing to text files:

- Write(string) - Writes a string to the open text file.
- WriteLine(string) - Writes a string to the text file and finishes it off with the new line character.
- WriteBlankLines(lines) - Writes a specified number of new line characters.

If you do not want a newline at the end, use

```
objFile.Write strNewText
```

instead of

```
objFile.WriteLine strNewText
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is mostly correct. It's not OpenTextFile that's adding a newline, it's WriteLine. If you replace that with Write, it will work as you expect.